# Beamer TOC on each subsection

Tags: beamer, table-of-contents

I am currently making a presentation using Beamer.
I have section, subsection, subsubsections in my presentation. I want to achieve the following:

1. The TOC at the starting of the presentation won't show subsubsections.
2. Starting of a subsection, I need a TOC of that subsection as well as subsubsections.

I know the first can be achieved using \setcounter{tocdepth}{2}.
But I can't get the second one. It would be better if the subsubsections of the current subsection is highlighted and others are faded. 
Please help me out.

note: I have checked this: [Beamer Mini-TOC](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/101206/beamer-mini-toc). However, the difference is I want a TOC at the starting of subsections.

I also have checked this: [Beamer Presentation: Show TOC at beginning of Unnumbered Subsection (Subsection*)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/108898/beamer-presentation-show-toc-at-beginning-of-unnumbered-subsection-subsection)
However, the difference is this shows the whole TOC (although shaded) at the starting of each subsection. I wanted a mini-TOC, particularly for the current subsection. If a subsection doesn't have a subsubsection, no TOC should be generated.

Comment: It would be helpful if your question would contain a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228)

Answer (score 4):

This did the job for me. Although not completely. But for all practical purposes, it is close enough.

```
\AtBeginSubsection[]{
  \frame<beamer>{ 
    \frametitle{Outline}   

\tableofcontents[currentsection,currentsubsection,sectionstyle=show/hide,subsectionstyle=show/shaded/hide,subsubsectionstyle=show/show/shaded/shaded]}
}
```

Comment: Can you point out what is missing to do the "job completely"?